# Elasticsearch cluster CPU maxing out at 100 request per second search queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

**The Problem:** I'm running a elastic search server cluster with four index's one has 4.5 million documents the other has 13 million. The other index's are the marvel and the kibana and are very small.

Whenever I get to about 150 queries per second with jmeter ("testing framework") The CPU will max out. The more I turn it up the more the CPU maxes out.

From everything I read online about performance tuning it usually has memory issues but our box is running out of cpu way before memory and causing 6 second response times with the test.

**the setup:**

```
3 x client nodes AWS m3.xlarge
4 cores 16gb
3 x master nodes AWS m3.medium
1 core 4gb <-i beleive
3 x data nodes   AWS c3.2xlarge
8 cores 30gb
```

**Plugins:**

```
  AWS
  Marvel
```

**Document Count**

```
account-index-v1.0   4.5 M
entry-index-v1.0     13.1 M
```

**@160 query per second using jmeter to execute the following query:**

```
            CPU  LOAD(1m) MEM  %FreeD   IOPS
Client Nodes
hidden:9300 0.0    0.0    7.3    n/a     n/a
hidden:9300 0.0    0.0    4.3    n/a     n/a
hidden:9300 0.0    0.1    8.3    n/a     n/a

Data Nodes
hidden:9300 99.0   10.2   11.7    69.7 GB  1.2
hidden:9300 71.0   3.0    15.0    69.6 GB  3.9
hidden:9300 16.7   0.3    12.7    69.8 GB  0.1

Master Nodes
hidden:9300 0.3    0.0    3.0     73.0 GB  0.2
hidden:9300 0.3    0.0    7.0     73.0 GB  0.1
hidden:9300 0.3    0.0    5.0     73.0 GB  0.1
```

**queries**

```
{
"match"{"event_id":"10000"},
"match"{"race_id_indexed":"10000"},
"match"{"is_test":"F"},
"match"{"status":"CONF"},
"must_not":[{"match"{"type":"TEAM"}}],
"query":{"match_all":{}}
}



marvel.agent.enabled: true
cluster.name: Vision
bootstrap.mlockall: true
http.enabled: true
index.number_of_shards: 3
index.number_of_replicas: 1

<%if node.has_key?("ec2") %>
plugin.mandatory: "cloud-aws"
discovery.type: "ec2"
discovery.ec2.groups: "<%= node["ec2"]["security_groups"][0] %>"
discovery.ec2.ping_timeout: "120s"
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
<% else %>
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: true
<% end %>
```

as per the comment I changed to using filters. The cpu usage went down but its still 60-70% at 160rps.

here is the query

```
{
    "search" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "event_id" : ["10000"], race_id_indexed:["100000"], is_test:["F"], status:["CONF"]}
        }
    }
}
```

the optimized query really helped the performance but im still getting high cpu usage according to marvel.

hot_threads:

```
::: [Gazelle][rJ0RbsKIQSeP5ozDb_U9oQ][esn2-a828d755-dev][inet[/10.11.180.189:9300]]{master=false}
   
   23.3% (116.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gazelle][search][T#6]'
     9/10 snapshots sharing following 10 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.awaitMatch(LinkedTransferQueue.java:735)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.xfer(LinkedTransferQueue.java:644)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.take(LinkedTransferQueue.java:1137)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.SizeBlockingQueue.take(SizeBlockingQueue.java:162)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     unique snapshot
       java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:433)
       org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger(Hierarchy.java:273)
       org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger(Hierarchy.java:247)
       org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
       org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
       org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.Log4jESLoggerFactory.newInstance(Log4jESLoggerFactory.java:39)
       org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:62)
       org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:147)
       org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:110)
       org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:84)
       org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractComponent.<init>(AbstractComponent.java:38)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.<init>(BigArrays.java:377)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.withCircuitBreaking(BigArrays.java:420)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.DefaultSearchContext.<init>(DefaultSearchContext.java:201)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:536)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:515)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:277)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   
   19.6% (98ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gazelle][search][T#9]'
     3/10 snapshots sharing following 19 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantScorer.nextDoc(ConstantScoreQuery.java:257)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:192)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     7/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   
   19.5% (97.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gazelle][search][T#7]'
     3/10 snapshots sharing following 19 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantScorer.nextDoc(ConstantScoreQuery.java:257)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:192)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     7/10 snapshots sharing following 10 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.awaitMatch(LinkedTransferQueue.java:735)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.xfer(LinkedTransferQueue.java:644)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.take(LinkedTransferQueue.java:1137)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.SizeBlockingQueue.take(SizeBlockingQueue.java:162)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: [Shiva][otF4wQ2MRy6IuIXNkJr8hw][esn3-c2c5423e-dev][inet[/10.111.181.149:9300]]{master=false}
   
   37.9% (189.3ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Shiva][search][T#9]'
     6/10 snapshots sharing following 18 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:193)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     4/10 snapshots sharing following 19 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantScorer.nextDoc(ConstantScoreQuery.java:257)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:192)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   
   32.2% (161ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Shiva][search][T#4]'
     5/10 snapshots sharing following 18 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:193)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     5/10 snapshots sharing following 19 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantScorer.nextDoc(ConstantScoreQuery.java:257)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:192)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   
   31.5% (157.6ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Shiva][search][T#11]'
     5/10 snapshots sharing following 18 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:193)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     5/10 snapshots sharing following 19 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantScorer.nextDoc(ConstantScoreQuery.java:257)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:192)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:272)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:283)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:776)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:767)
       org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

::: [Rachel Summers][FBCqMCL8QiuyaBDDT9tvqg][esn1-38caed17-dev][inet[/10.145.222.206:9300]]{master=false}
   
   15.3% (76.3ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Rachel Summers][search][T#1]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   
   12.9% (64.6ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Rachel Summers][search][T#9]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 10 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.awaitMatch(LinkedTransferQueue.java:735)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.xfer(LinkedTransferQueue.java:644)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.take(LinkedTransferQueue.java:1137)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.SizeBlockingQueue.take(SizeBlockingQueue.java:162)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   
   11.9% (59.6ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Rachel Summers][search][T#10]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 10 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.awaitMatch(LinkedTransferQueue.java:735)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.xfer(LinkedTransferQueue.java:644)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.take(LinkedTransferQueue.java:1137)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.SizeBlockingQueue.take(SizeBlockingQueue.java:162)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try replacing these match queries with term filters and if it's still slow please post result of the hot threads command during high CPU load: `curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads` It will show the areas of elasticsearch where CPU is utilized.

Comment: thanks ill update you in a bit, just running some test with jmeter now.

Comment: @imotov added more info thanks :)

Comment: Could you wrap your terms filter into constant_score query instead of using it in top level filter and repeat the test? By the way, you shouldn't use answer to add more information regarding the questions, it messes things up and other users will start downvoting it.

Comment: @imotov I ran out of character space, I could've just attached a file I guess. Yea I tried it that way at least how the ES guide shows you to do it, can you give me an example?

Comment: @imotov my load is at 11.8 with 8 cores.